# discord bot sending multiple messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

my scheduled message bot code is working but I have no idea how to prevent from sending multiple messages at the same time

```
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")
    while True:
        time = datetime.datetime.today()
        if time.hour == 2:
         if time.minute == 39:
           await Bot.get_channel(<channel id>).send(f"Good Morning")
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a `Task` for this, this is what they're designed for... https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html 2.0 added support to run a task at a specific moment of the day (in your case, `2:30`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean variable that indicates whether you have already sent the message at 2:39 am.

```
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")
    sent = False
    while True:
        time = datetime.datetime.today()
        if time.hour == 2:
         if time.minute == 39:
           if not sent:
             sent = True
             await Bot.get_channel(<channel id>).send(f"Good Morning")
         else:
             sent = False
```

It depends on a thousand factors how you want to implement the control. You can also sleep for 1 minute using sleep(60), or exit the loop once the event is triggered (break)